# Magento 2 - Get Category Name in block

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, blocks, theme

I'm trying to get the category name in a block for the home page
so that when the visitor changes the language, the name of the category will translate depending on the selected language, like with the top menu.

I search for it and all I found is have to be done in .phtml file 
Is there any way to do it in a block?

Comment: @Hello Salim, what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Hi PHILLIP JACKSON I could not fix and I did not find any way for fix it do you have any idea